# How to upload file to server from HTML Post ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload a file to server from html post.

```
<form action="insertBlogCat.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="uploader" name="userfile" type="file" />

        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="pxUpload" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="pxClear" />
    </form>
```

My server side code:

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile CatBlogImgFile;
 private void Insert()
        {

            if ((CatBlogImgFile.PostedFile != null) && (CatBlogImgFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CatBlogImgFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;
                try
                {
                    CatBlogImgFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
            }
        }
```

But CatBlogImgFile.PostedFile value is always null after posting from HTML file. PLease help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix normal HTML elements and server-side controls like that.

Either use ASP.Net WebControls in the ASPX page (`<asp:FileUpload />`), or use the `Request` object directly and don't use server-side controls at all (`Request.Files`)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if the [Request.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.files.aspx) collection has any content.  Normally in WebForms, you'd use a different control for doing uploads.

You may also want to look over the MSDN article: [How to: Add HTML Server Controls to a Web Page Using ASP.NET Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s37470tf%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) .  The main thing you're missing is the `runat="server"` part.